# I have SQL Server instance and I want to connect it with a Windows VM both are in GCP in the same default public VPC

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, cloud, firewall

I'm new to GCP and I am struggling to setup a connection between the SQL Server and Windows VM, for now, I'm using the external IP of the Windows VM to add it to SQL Server connection, to whitelist it making it possible for me to connect it with the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio that I have in the windows VM, but the external IP is dynamic and I have to manually add the new ip again and again. Is there any way to solve this.

Steps I followed to troubleshoot

The firewall rules I have set an connection for TCP - 1433 which is the default connection.

The SQL Server connection IP is pinging in my windows VM (this is before i whitelisted the external IP)

I have also tried to connect using the SQL Server cmd tool

```
sqlcmd -S <server_address> -U <username> -P <password> 

sqlcmd -S <server_address> -U <username> -P <password> -d <database_name> -P <port_number>
```

and I'm getting this error

> sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login failed for user 'username'..

PS: most of the documents I saw were in cloud sql but I am using SQL Server.

Thanks

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address

Comment: It sounds like you're establishing a connection successfully but then the login process itself is failing. For security reasons login failure messages on the client side are intentionally vague. Can you check the Error Log on the target instance, look for Error 18456 events, take note of the State numbers in them and compare those against [MSSQLSERVER_18456](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error) to see what the actual login problem is?